# Knockout dependency injection

Tags: knockout.js

I've just seen in a great KO manual an example of creating a new class within a self invokation function, in a way that "should not pollute the global namespace".
I could not understand why they send the myApp (the current namespace) into the "inner scope", if it anyways existed in the outer scope. As far as I know, if you send an object to a js function, it will be passed by ref, so that any change will be reflected outside of the function either. So why 'injecting' the myApp inside? :

```
window.myApp = {};
(function (myApp) {
    function Product() {
        var self = this;
        self.sku = ko.observable("");
        self.description = ko.observable("");
        self.price = ko.observable(0.00);
        self.cost = ko.observable(0.00);
        self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    }
    myApp.Product = Product;
}} (window.myApp));
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these reasons to scope the variable.

1. Let minifiers replace the variable to a shorter name inside the function.
2. Keep reference to the original object if the global variable is overwritten.
3. Prevent local variables within the scope to be globally accessible, similar to 2.

That said, it might not be an issue in this simple case.

For example, reason 1:

```
window.myApp = {};
(function (x) {
    function Product() {
        var self = this;
        self.sku = ko.observable("");
        self.description = ko.observable("");
        self.price = ko.observable(0.00);
        self.cost = ko.observable(0.00);
        self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    }
    x.Product = Product;
}} (window.myApp));
```

For example, reason 2:

```
window.myApp = {};
(function (myApp) {
    myApp.counter = 0;

    function Product() {
        // removed for clarity.

        myApp.counter++;
    }

    // Code that depends on the myApp (global) varible. 
    // It will break if anyone overwrites the global variable.

    myApp.Product = Product;
}} (window.myApp));

window.myApp = {}; // Will break the scoped code if it wasn't scoped.
```

For example, reason 3:

```
window.myApp = {};
(function (myApp) {
    var counter = 0;

    function Product() {
        // removed for clarity.

        counter++;
    }

    myApp.Product = Product;
}} (window.myApp));
```